# gls does not give correct intercept and slope during multiple regression

Tags: r, nlme

Anybody could please tell me why gls function sometimes does not give the correct intercept and slope for a given [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkfd9xgylj5131o/exampleglsabline.csv?dl=0)? Here is a reproducible example:

```
  require(nlme)
  s=read.csv("exampleglsabline.csv")
  m1=gls(log(y)~log(x2)+log(x1),method="REML",data =  s)
  summary(m1)
  x=s$x1
  y=residuals(gls(log(y)~log(x2),method="REML",data =  s))
  plot(x,y,xlab="x1",ylab=expression("y"),
  type = 'p',bg=adjustcolor("seashell", alpha=0.8), col = 'black',cex=2, pch=21,cex.lab=1,
  xlim=c(min(0),max(x)),
  ylim=c(min(y),max(y)))
  abline(a=7.251864,b=0.882575)
```

[image]

Comment: scale your variables: `scale(log(y))~scale(log(x2))`, and have `x=log(s$x1)`

Comment: First get the example straight. Then provide the data so that we can reproduce your result.

Comment: Thanks user2957945, this works indeed. Would you tell me why the scaling is necessary? and why only scaling the data , without taking logs first, leads to different relationships?

Comment: @ Roman Luštrik, I did not understand your answer. The data was available and the example runs smoothly with it.